# Products not appearing under content in admin in Drupal Commerce

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I am importing products using Commerce Feeds.  The products appear just fine on the front end and via Store > Products in the admin.  However no products appear under Content in the admin area.  I have tried clearing out the database, re-importing, re-indexing, flushing caches - nothing works.

Also this is bizarre and seemingly un-related, however I noticed it around the same time I realized my products were not appearing in the admin - there is a strange whitespace above my admin menu bar - which only appears on the Content page (also coincidently the page giving me trouble.)  [image: Whitespace above menu bar]

Using Commerce Kickstart (commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.0-rc1) (Would love to upgrade to the latest release but I am unsure how to do this without losing a great deal of work.  I have not found a good upgrade document - please chime in if you know something I don't!)

Comment: Oh, before I get this question - I am importing both products and product display.  I can see all of the products I have imported with the type of "product_display" when I query the node table.  I just don't see them in the admin area.

Answer (score 1):

I feel kind of stupid now.  I edited the admin/content view and saw there was a filter criteria which caused it to not display nodes of type "product_display."  Evidently this is intentional behavior.  I am guessing you are only supposed to manage products from within the store tab.  Still wish I could figure out the cause of the phantom whitespace at the top though.